# What is the least complex way to implement a DP3T ON-X-ON switch?

Tags: pcb, switches, pcb-design, circuit-design, wiring

I have an application below that requires 2 MCUs to be on a PCB, along with a single FTDI header. Both are programmed thru their RX/TX UART pins.

In normal operation, the RX pin on MCU_1 is connected to TX pin on MCU_2, and vice versa, for inter-MCU communication.

To flash MCU_1, a DP3T switch is toggled to the left to route the MCU_1 TX/RX pins to the FTDI header.

To flash MCU_2, the switch is toggled to the right to route the MCU_2 TX/RX pins to the FTDI header.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOHqjl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

So far, I have found DP3T switches with the following configurations:
[image: DP3T configurations]

I'm looking for such a configuration instead:

[image: ON-X-ON]

I'm guessing such a switch probably doesn't exist? How is it best then, using the least wiring/components as possible, to implement such a setup?

Comment: Can you guarantee that all the TX outputs will be tristated when the switch is thrown?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Hmm the switch should not be thrown during normal operation (i.e. MCU1 <--> MCU2 inter-communication). It serves as some kinda debug switch to allow the user to connect up a FTDI programmer to flash each MCU without having to remove either MCU from the board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can guarantee that all the TX outputs will be tristated (floating) when the switch is thrown, then you can use a [4P3T slide switch](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/e-switch/EG4319/EG1915-ND/101784) wired as follows, for the given switch:

- 1 and 3 to MCU 1's TX
- 4 and 7 to MCU 2's TX
- 5 and 8 to the FTDI's TX
- 2 to 10
- 6 to 14
- 9 and 12 to the FTDI's RX
- 11 and 16 to MCU 2's RX
- and 13 and 15 to MCU 1's RX

P.S. the lack of a schematic is due to CircuitLab not having appropriate symbols for a 4P3T switch.

Comment: Nice, thanks a bunch! I have made a [schematic](http://i.imgur.com/1ZEwLUA.png) from the datasheet to visualize this. Straightforward and perfect!